# How to get async conditional property inside Angular *ngFor loop of complex object

Tags: angular, loops, asynchronous, observable

Let's assume I have empty observable object, which is filled up at some moment of time, with such data:

```
const props$ =
{
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 2,
  prop3: 3,
}
```

And I have a loop with such data:

```
const loopData =
[
 { property: "prop1", label: "First" },
 { property: "prop2", label: "Second" },
 { property: "prop3", label: "Third" },
]
```

And here my HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of loopData">
    <label>{{ obj.label }}</label>
    <span>{{(props$ | async)?.obj.property}}</span> <---- this line of code will not work
</div>
```

If I make those line like this `(props$ | async)?[obj.property]` compiler will complain to ask `:` after `]`, thinking that I am trying to write condition in one line, which available in ES6.
So that, is there any case how can I do that clearer.
One thought I have come with is to do it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of loopData">
    <label>{{ obj.label }}</label>
    <ng-container *ngIf="props$ | async as props">
        <span>{{props[obj.property]}}</span>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this will work (see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbs4sa):

```html
<li *ngFor="let obj of loopData">
  <label>{{obj.label}}</label>
  <span>{{(props$ | async)[obj.property]}}</span>
</li>
```

If you need the null check then I think it is easiest to extract to a function in the component (see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epvtnh):

```html
<li *ngFor="let obj of loopData">
  <label>{{obj.label}}</label>
  <span>{{getPropertyValue(props$ | async, obj.property)}}</span>
</li>
```

```js
getPropertyValue(props: Record<string, number>, propertyName: string) {
  return props ? props[propertyName] : null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but why can't I just wrap element with async pipe in ng-template, as I showed in my question? It looks clearer, doesn't it?

Comment: I think it is not possible to use a safe navigation operator `.?` followed by the bracket notation `[]` to access the element's properties.

Comment: You didn't understand me. I will post my solution below. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have got one workable solution from @mike-jerred. But I guess my answer can also be as a solution.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let obj of loopData">
    <label>{{obj.label}}</label>
    <ng-container *ngIf="props$ | async as props">
        <span>{{props[obj.property]}}</span>
    </ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, quoting the documentation for safe navigation operator

> Safe navigation operator is denoted as (?.) and it is used while we
>   are accessing a property from an object.

The first expression you have written is

```
 <span>{{(props$ | async)?.obj.property}}</span>
```

This treats `(props$ | async)` as object and then treats `.obj` as its property and another property chained to it as `.property` which is not the case you want.

`object.property` results in a value and you need to pass this value as a lookup in brackets to `props$`.

Safe navigator operator works on accessing property of an object using dot notation and it does not work on property lookup using brackets. (e.g. object[lookup])